# UI Automation for Prism wpf project using White

Tags: wpf, microsoft-ui-automation, prism-5

I have created WPF application using Prism framework. Now I need to perform UI automation on it. I have used White UI automation framework for plain WPF application, but I am not able to write UI test in Prism using White.

How to write UI test in Prism application.

Are there any other frameworks to perform UI automation test apart from White and Coded UI?

Comment: What do you mean "not able to write UI test in Prism..."? Does the framework not see the controls of the Prism application? To the best of my knowledge White and Coded UI use the same underlying Microsoft framework which is UIA. The main alternative is UFT which relies on image recognition.

Comment: Yes. I am not able to get hold of window, say shell.xaml or user control inside shell. Is there a way to catch them in UI tree? I am using white for the first time.

Comment: Just downloaded a sample WPF Prism application (called Scribble) and its controls seem to be visible using the UIA inspect tool, so it should also be visible using White framework. Can you be more specific about what application you are trying to test and what the problem is exactly?